# Can't cast int to T, where T is bool. Is there a way to do this with C#?

Tags: c#, int, casting, boolean

I'll try to be quick, as I already made exhaustive search on this topic and I only find topics related to converting bool into int.

I built a class to handle sparse matrices. They could be filled by double, int or bool, or any other value type.

To get some matrix element at position i,j:

```
public T getElementValueAt(int i, int j)
{
    int ind = this.doesElemExist(i, j); 
         // returns the element index if it exists, or -1
    return (ind == -1 ? (T)(object)0 : this.elem[ind].value );
}
```

Before going on, one highlight on bad practices above, and other about sparse matrices:

1. I've been searching and found that `(T)(object)0` is not a good practice, but I don't see why can't I use it here, as it works whether T is int or double;
2. If the element I want to get is not on the list `this.elem`, I should return 0 typed correctly in accordance with the other elements type.

So it boils down to converting an int value (0, in this case) to a certain type T, which is a type parameter.

Any good way to do this? Any comments about this approach?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type is `elem[ind].value`, and is there a reason it is not of type `T` ?

Comment: I think you would want `default(T)` instead of `(T)(object)0`

Comment: the property value is already T typed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your cast of `(T)(object)0` *won't* work if `T` is `double`... it will throw an `InvalidCastException` when it tries to unbox a boxed `int` to `double`.

I suspect what you *actually* want is `default(T)`, which gives the default value of whatever `T` is - so null for a reference type, zero for numeric types etc:

```
return ind == -1 ? default(T) : this.elem[ind].value;
```

As a side-note, I'd encourage you to try to stick to .NET naming conventions, including PascalCase for methods.

Three other options:

- Use `Nullable<T>` as suggested in other answers
- Follow the `TryXXX` approach of returning a Boolean value to indicate whether the element was found, and have an `out` parameter to receive the value itself
- Use a modified version of the `TryXXX` pattern where you return a `Tuple<bool, T>` instead of using an `out` parameter

Comment: Where can I find the naming conventions?

Answer (score 5):

You can use default(T). But you should consider using nullable types, too. (the function should return T? where T : struct).

Comment: Add "where T : struct" to your class. Make your function return T?. Then you can return null if the element doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use next:

```
Convert.ToBoolean(int);
```

Comment: It's not what I'm seeking as I want to cast the "0" into the type parameter T, which happens to be bool or int or double

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered returning default(T) instead of 0?